# How to Get the Ajax success message event more than once in succession

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-animate

I have a form that fills in a codeigniter calender. First off I will say the form works just fine with Ajax & my controller. The first time I submit the form all data goes to the database and I get my success event which is just repeating what I entered, then it fades out. Works great.

The second time I enter data(I usually enter data into the database at least 5-6 times in succession) the data goes to the database but no second event message. Or 3rd, 4th etc.

My question is **how do I make the success callback fire each time I submit the form?**

My jquery

```
$(function() {
$('.error').hide();
$("#calen").submit(function() {
var data = $('#calen').serialize();
$.ajax({
url: ("http://XXXXXX.net/mycal/cale"),
data: data,
type: "POST",
success: function(msg){
    $('#cal').append(msg);
    $('#cal').delay(5000).fadeOut(1500);
    }      

});
return false;
});
});
```

I know this has to be simple. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you *fadeOut*, but never fade back in.  Try adding :

```
$('#cal').fadeIn(1500);
```

right before you append the message to the element.

Comment: That works in Firefox, not in chrome with is ok. However it also shows the previous inputs. On the 3rd input it shows 2012-04-22 - test12012-04-22 test22012-04-22 test3. Strange but I can live with it

Comment: @Brad if you want to clear the previous inputs, it should be fairly straightforward.  If the **cal** div is empty to begin with, you can just use the *html* method instead of *append*.  Otherwise you'd have to write a bit more login to ensure that your original template in **cal** is preserved.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I probably should have used html to start with. I assume append is keeping everything I previously submitted

Comment: @Brad yes, correct.  There's also *prepend*, *wrap* and a bunch more manipulation functions.  Check out the JQuery documentation if you're interested: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: Im just taking the Jquery 30 days lessons over at nettuts, Im sure that will help. I am afraid I havent started thinking the code through correctly yet

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the first update will hide the div.  I don't see that youve re-shown the `#cal` div for the second update. Have you tried doing that, or putting an alert there to see if it's actually being fired?

Comment: Its definitely being fired according to firebug